# How come manipulating registers (e.g. EAX) in Assembly doesn't affect other programs?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, architecture

Suppose, for example, I'm moving a value into the EAX register in Assembly for a program:

```
mov eax, 50 ;move the value 50 into register EAX
```

The registers of the processor are used by other programs, presumably. How come by manipulating their contents I'm not interfering with other programs that require their use? Is it because of different threads of execution, and if so, how exactly is this managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler follows a calling convention that depending on the compiler and processor may include a list of registers that are free for a function to use without preserving and others that if you use them you must preserve them (generally on the stack but that is up to the implementation).  Inline assembly, to work properly, has to tell the compiler in some way what registers are being used (or let the compiler choose) so that the compiler can work around the assembly as far as the register preservation rules go and as far as what registers the function wanted to use for things may have to change.   Threads are just another level above that as well as processor modes (interrupt and other exceptions) where the rule is generally to save state of everything, all registers and the processor status word.   So that if/when you return the code that was interrupted from an execution stand point does not know that it had been interrupted (all registers are put back the way they were found).

Answer (score 3):

As you suspect, each thread has its own copy of every register. This context, as it is known, is preserved by the operating system when it switches between threads.

Answer (score 3):

You may also wonder "How come that - if you use a specific register yourself - calling a subroutine which makes use of that register doesn't interfere with your own use of that register?" - The answer is pretty much the same: every piece of code which modifies contents of a register which is not known to be free for use - because saved elsewhere already - must save original contents, and later restore register to its previous value.

The "saved elsewhere already" is what applies to threads, therefore you don't need to take care of saving/restoring yourself.